# Python Timed Rotating Logs

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Asking for some clarification on this article in the section labeled "TimedRotatingLogs": https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/02/11/python-how-to-create-rotating-logs/

```
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path,
                                       when="m",
                                       interval=1,
                                       backupCount=5)
```

I am curious about this part in particular. When looking at the article it says for "WeekDay" do "w0-w6".
Would that look like this? :

```
        handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path,
                                       when="w",
                                       interval=0,
                                       backupCount=5)
```

Or would it look like:

```
 handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path,
                                       when="w0",
                                       interval=1,
                                       backupCount=5)
```

And explain why one over the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the article on [Kite Docs](https://kite.com/docs/python;logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler). It states that

> When using weekday-based rotation, specify ‘W0’ for Monday, ‘W1’ for
>   Tuesday, and so on up to ‘W6’ for Sunday. In this case, the value
>   passed for interval isn’t used.

So going from there The code in your case would be

```
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path, when="w0", backupCount=5)
```